# SAPUI5 Javascript - Get first and last elements of array for each unique property

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, sapui5

SAPUI5 - I have an array of objects and one of the properties in those is 'Category'.

For example say I have 2 different types of Category, 'Front Shop' and 'Production Area', what I need to do is to be able to get the first value of each and the last value of each, and then set the enabled property of a button as enabled/disabled.

I'm currently using undercore js (_.each) to loop through to perform some other logic, so can include additional logic here.

Not sure if Underscore has a built in function for this? 
Or could someone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

I've got my first pass at what was wanted where I get the very first result and the last result, but now need to set this for each unique category.

[image]

Example code below:

```
// Set view data
                oViewData.Questions = oQuestions.results;
                oViewData.Questions.TotalNumberOfQuestions = oQuestions.results.length;

                // Loop Questions, to get Category Desc and Competency Desc values from relevant Sets
                _.each(oViewData.Questions, function (result, index) {

                    // Read and set Category Desc
                    this.getView().getModel("Survey").read("/CategorySet", {
                        filters: [new Filter("CategoryId", FilterOperator.EQ, result.CategoryId)],
                        success: function (oData) {
                            oViewData.Questions[index]._CategoryDesc = oData.results[0].CategoryDesc;
                            this.setViewData(oViewData);
                        }.bind(this),
                        error: function (oError) {}.bind(this)
                    });

                    // Read and set Competency Desc
                    this.getView().getModel("Survey").read("/CompetencySet", {
                        filters: [new Filter("CompetencyId", FilterOperator.EQ, result.CompetencyId)],
                        success: function (oData) {
                            oViewData.Questions[index]._CompetencyDesc = oData.results[0].CompetencyDesc;
                            this.setViewData(oViewData);
                        }.bind(this),
                        error: function (oError) {}.bind(this)
                    });

                    // Set all move up / down buttons to enabled
                    oViewData.Questions[index]._MoveUpBtn = true;
                    oViewData.Questions[index]._MoveDownBtn = true;

                    // if category id is the first one in the list 



                }.bind(this));

                // Overwrite first move up button and last move down btn to disabled
                oViewData.Questions[0]._MoveUpBtn = false;
                oViewData.Questions.slice(-1)[0]._MoveDownBtn = false;

                // Set view data
                this.setViewData(oViewData);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can iterate through arrays with native JavaScript.

`_.each(array, function(item) {})` is the same as `array.forEach(function(item) {})`.

Second, you can use the built-in `filter` function for your actual question:

```
const aFrontShopItems = oViewData.Questions.filter(function(oItem) {
    return oItem.Category === "Front Shop";
}
```

If `oViewData.Questions` is an array then the function passed to `filter` is applied to every element. If the condition (e.g. `oItem.Category === "Front Shop"`) is true then the element is added to the new array `aFrontShopItems`. Obviously you need to call filter a second time to get the Production Area items. You can then apply your logic to the first and last items of your new arrays.